# How to end a loop with a grep in a temporary file?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm stuck!

I have a script. I want to check if a user is a system user (thanks to @pLumo).

I extract my no-system user in a temporary file and I grep to check if my variable is in my temporary file. 
Problem is, I can't quit my loop when I press q cause the grep command doesn't find
the user "q" in the temporary file.

```
     read -p "Enter the username you want to delete (q to quit) " name

     user=$( cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -w "^$name$" ) 2>>/dev/null         
     awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 <= 60000 && $6 ~ /^\/home/ {print $1}' /etc/passwd >/tmp/testuser

     if [ "$name" != "q" ]
     then        
       until [ $(grep -w "$user" /tmp/testuser) ] && [[ "$name" =~ $regex ]]  && [[ ! -z "$name" ]] && [ "$name" != "q" ]
       do
          read -p "User system or nonexistant, try again (q to quit) " name
          user=$( cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -w "^$name$" ) 2>>/dev/null
       done      
          if [ "$name" = "q" ]
          then
            echo "You quit the program"
            exit
          fi
     fi
```

Comment: maybe I'm biased but I think this dude here has got a *pretty* neat solution to this : https://github.com/tatsujb/installFAFscript/blob/master/install_FA_script.sh#L114 if you like this solution I can draft it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I don't find his solution to my problem. Can you explain please?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Videonauth thanks but it doesn't take into account the algorithm.

Comment: @danaso the trick used is to time the read command with `-t 1` (for one second) so basically you add a second read. and each has it's seperate prrompt, so the user knows when he can type the username and when he can type q to exit. it should work. I don't know if that's your ideal solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `if`-block needs to be included in the `until`-loop. A check for the entered name has to added after the first `read`-command.

```
     read -p "Enter the username you want to delete (q to quit) " name

     if [ "$name" = "q" ]
     then
       echo "You quit the program"
       exit
     fi

     user=$( cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -w "^$name$" ) 2>>/dev/null         
     awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 <= 60000 && $6 ~ /^\/home/ {print $1}' /etc/passwd >/tmp/testuser

     if [ "$name" != "q" ]
     then        
       until [ $(grep -w "$user" /tmp/testuser) ] && [[ "$name" =~ $regex ]]  && [[ ! -z "$name" ]] && [ "$name" != "q" ]
       do
          read -p "User system or nonexistant, try again (q to quit) " name         
          if [ "$name" = "q" ]
          then
            echo "You quit the program"
            exit
          fi
          user=$( cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -w "^$name$" ) 2>>/dev/null
       done
     fi
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. The second if-block is for the second read -p e.g when the program asks the name again.

Comment: Ah, I see, should be better now...

Comment: Thanks! it works!